# Memtest Errors but Pass = 1

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I ran memtest86 on my computer and got an error. However the output has a 1 in the pass column. What does this mean and is the RAM still faulty/at risk of BSOD?

[image]

Comment: pass1 means the first pass of test #3, you have a bad memory module.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't think about the alternate meaning of 'pass'. Thanks.

Comment: Pass 1 means test suite has completed one full run, memtest runs forever unless you stop it so it has to let you know how many full passes it has completed